# Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

As mentioned at [Terraform Resource: Connection Error while executing apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63613944/terraform-resource-connection-error-while-executing-apply)

I changed my code to the the below

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      host        = aws_eip.nat-eip.public_ip
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = file("/id_rsa.pem")
    }
    inline = [
      "chmod +x /tmp/start_node.sh",
      "sudo sed -i -e 's/\r$//' /tmp/start_node.sh", # Remove the spurious CR characters.
      "sudo /tmp/start_node.sh",
    ]
  }
```

But I still get the same error

```
Error: Invalid function argument

  on explorer.tf line 60, in resource "aws_instance" "explorer":
  60:       private_key = file("/id_rsa.pem")

Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at /id_rsa.pem;

this function works only with files that are distributed as part of the
configuration source code, so if this file will be created by a resource in
this configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of
that resource.
```

`ls -la` ooutput

````
total 156
drwxr-xr-x  10 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users  4096 Jan 12 14:29 .
drwxr-xr-x  16 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users  4096 Jan 10 13:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x  12 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users  4096 Jan 12 09:49 byoc-terraform
drwxr-xr-x   2 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users  4096 Jan 11 11:57 controllers
-rw-r--r--   1 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users   188 Jan 10 13:27 .env
-rw-r--r--   1 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users  1582 Jan 10 17:12 fetchUserData.js
drwxr-xr-x   9 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users  4096 Jan 12 13:14 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users   629 Jan 10 13:27 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--   1 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users   107 Dec 30 06:49 .gitmodules
-rw-r--r--   1 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users  1765 Jan 12 13:21 id_rsa.pem
-rw-r--r--   1 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users  1488 Jan 10 13:27 index.js
drwxr-xr-x   3 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users  4096 Jan 10 13:27 models
drwxr-xr-x 221 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users 12288 Jan 10 13:30 node_modules
-rw-r--r--   1 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users  1058 Jan 10 13:27 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users 78791 Jan 10 13:27 package-lock.json
drwxr-xr-x   2 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users  4096 Jan 10 13:27 routes
drwxr-xr-x   2 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users  4096 Jan 10 17:01 utils
drwxr-xr-x   2 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users  4096 Jan 10 13:27 VMCreationFiles```
````

Comment: Don't paste error messages as images - they are not indexable for search (at least as of 2021) - i.e. others might not be able to find your question and benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it .

Comment: Can you run `ls -la /id*` and post the output? It seems your private key is in a different location

Comment: ```[CORP\mayuresh@a-2xr1uki591z7i byoc-backend]$ ls -la /id*
ls: cannot access /id*: No such file or directory
[CORP\mayuresh@a-2xr1uki591z7i byoc-backend]$ ls
byoc-terraform  fetchUserData.js  index.js  node_modules  package-lock.json  utils
controllers     id_rsa.pem        models    package.json  routes             VMCreationFiles
[CORP\mayuresh@a-2xr1uki591z7i byoc-backend]$ ```

Comment: I have also added the full ls -la in the question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ```[CORP\mayuresh@a-2xr1uki591z7i byoc-backend]$ ls -la id*```
```-rw-r--r-- 1 CORP\mayuresh CORP\domain users 1765 Jan 12 13:21 id_rsa.pem```

Comment: Where is your `explorer.tf`? Your ls printout does not show such a file.

Comment: explorer.tf is in the folder ```byoc-terraform``` and there as well I placed a copy of ```id_rsa.pem``` in every directory I placed a copy of this pem file to be extra sure but it doesnt read it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path to the `.pem` is wrong. It looks like the file exists in your $HOME directory.

You can provide the absolute path of the `id_rsa.pem` file if that file is outside of `path.module, path.root, path.cwd`

To provide the absolute path

1. Fetch the full path of the file [How to get full path of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265702/how-to-get-full-path-of-a-file)
2. Paste the path in:

   ```
   provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      host        = aws_eip.nat-eip.public_ip
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = file("<Absolute path to .pem file e.g /home/ubuntu/id_rsa.pem>")
    }
   ```

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried using the full path? Especially beneficial if you are using modules.
I.E:

```
private_key = file("${path.module}/id_rsa.pem")
```

Or I think even this will work

```
private_key = file("./id_rsa.pem")
```

I believe your existing code is looking for the file at the root of your filesystem.

Comment: Yes, I tried both of it. Also, I tried plugging in full path after getting it from PWD but nothing seems to work as of yet.

Comment: Can you show me the full file in question please and how and from what directory you are running terraform from?

Comment: adding ${path.module} to the file name worked for me.  I am using Ubuntu on WSL2.

Comment: `${path.module}` works for me on MacOS Ventura!