# Gateway rest API resource can't find the file I provide

Tags: json, terraform, aws-api-gateway

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api" {
  body = "${file("apigateway/json-resolved/swagger.json")}"
  name = "api"
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at apigateway/json-resolved/swagger.json;
this function works only with files that are distributed as 
part of the configuration source code, 
so if this file will be created by a resource in this configuration you must 
instead obtain this result from an attribute of that resource.
```

When I try to deploy my API by providing the actual path to the API JSON, this is what it throws. Even though the file is there, even though I tried different paths, from relative to absolute, etc. It works when I paste the entire JSON in the body, but not when I provide a file. Why is that?

Comment: You need a leading `./` or alternatively if the file is in a subdirectory compared to where you are running the code from, you could use `path.cwd`, e.g., ${file("${path.cwd}/apigateway/json-resolved/swagger.json")}"

Comment: See https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/file

Comment: @MarkoE Recommend to convert to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Terraform is not aware of the location of the file, you should specify it explicitly:

1. If the file is in the same directory, then use `./apigateway/json-resolved/swagger.json`
2. If the file is one directory up from the directory you are running Terraform from, you could use `../apigateway/json-resolved/swagger.json`
3. Alternatively, it is a good idea to use Terraform built-in functions for path manipulation: `path.cwd`, `path.module`, or `path.root`. More detailed explanation about what these three functions represent can be found in [1].
4. Provide a full path to the file by running `pwd` in the directory where the file is located (this works on Linux and MacOS) and paste the result of the command in the `file` function input.

Additionally, any combination of the points 2. and 3. could also work, but you should be careful.

There is also another great answer to a similar question [2].

NOTE: in some cases the `path.*` functions might not give expected results on Windows. As per this comment [3] from Github, if the paths are used consistently (i.e., all `/` or all `\`), Windows should also be able to work with `path.*` but only for versions of Terraform `>=0.12`. Based on the code snippet form the question it seems in this case an older version is used.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references#filesystem-and-workspace-info

[2] [Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65680044/invalid-value-for-path-parameter-no-file-exists-at)

[3] https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/14986#issuecomment-448756885